# Error while searching location in osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

hi when i am trying to search location on open street maps i am getting Geo Coding error.please help me. i am using osm bonus pack also but also i am getting error.
When i am pressing search button it is showing exception in catch block so please help me friends.

```
public void handleSearchButton(int index, int editResId){
        EditText locationEdit = (EditText)findViewById(editResId);
        //Hide the soft keyboard:
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(locationEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);

        String locationAddress = locationEdit.getText().toString();

        if (locationAddress.equals("")){
            removePoint(index);
            map.invalidate();
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching:\n"+locationAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AutoCompleteOnPreferences.storePreference(this, locationAddress, SHARED_PREFS_APPKEY, PREF_LOCATIONS_KEY);
        GeocoderNominatim geocoder = new GeocoderNominatim(this);
        geocoder.setOptions(true); //ask for enclosing polygon (if any)
        try {
            List<Address> foundAdresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
            if (foundAdresses.size() == 0) { //if no address found, display an error
                Toast.makeText(this, "Address not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Address address = foundAdresses.get(0); //get first address
                if (index == START_INDEX){
                    startPoint = new GeoPoint(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    markerStart = putMarkerItem(markerStart, startPoint, START_INDEX,
                        R.string.departure, R.drawable.marker_departure, -1);
                    map.getController().setCenter(startPoint);
                } else if (index == DEST_INDEX){
                    destinationPoint = new GeoPoint(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    markerDestination = putMarkerItem(markerDestination, destinationPoint, DEST_INDEX,
                        R.string.destination, R.drawable.marker_destination, -1);
                    map.getController().setCenter(destinationPoint);
                }
                getRoadAsync();
                //get and display enclosing polygon:
                Bundle extras = address.getExtras();
                if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("polygonpoints")){
                    ArrayList<GeoPoint> polygon = extras.getParcelableArrayList("polygonpoints");
                    //Log.d("DEBUG", "polygon:"+polygon.size());
                    updateUIWithPolygon(polygon);
                } else {
                    updateUIWithPolygon(null);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Geocoding error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant exception and tell us on which code line it occurs.

Comment: when search destination address it is executing it is coming out of try block and executing catch blocking and showing Geocoding error in catch block.

Comment: Please show us exactly your exception by printing `e.getMessage()`. Without this information it is impossible to know what did go wrong.